# React Native: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded."

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement `country-state-city` in React native (with Expo) and I have prebuilt the app. But whenever I attempt to run it on a physical device I get

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

at node_modules\expo\build\logs\LogSerialization.js:156:18 in _captureConsoleStackTrace

...
```

Any way to resolve this? Or is there a different library I can implement?

Comment: hey can you share your code, there's some re rendering happening hwich is causing this issue

Comment: Theres two lines of code causing the issue:
```import { Country, State, City } from "country-state-city";

const countries = Country.getAllCountries();
```
When I add the Country.getAllCountries() it crashes

Comment: happens due to weird useEffect dependency array .trying empty it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Jjkivai just saw the repo, so acc to issues on github its not compatible with RN. but some user has forked the library and tweaked it so that it can be  used with RN

https://github.com/harpreetkhalsagtbit/country-state-city/issues/16#issuecomment-504103073

[Github link](https://github.com/harpreetkhalsagtbit/country-state-city/issues/16#issuecomment-504103073)

DO check it out and hope it helps.

Comment: The fork removes ```cities``` functionality, which I need for my project. From my understanding, it's due to trying to load ```cities.json``` which is 1 million+ lines. Is there a way to efficiently load it?

Comment: damnn, i guess you would need to contact your backend team on sending that more effieiecnly